# discover the properties of $v'(t)=f(v)=-g-\frac{kv|v|}{m}$ without solving it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to discover some of the properties of the differential equation $v'(t)=f(v)=-g-\frac{kv|v|}{m}$ where $g, k, m$ are positive constant. Here I found that $v_0=-\sqrt{mg/k}$ is the equilibrium point, i.e $f(v_0)=0$, therefore $v_0(t)=v_0$ would be a solution of the differential equation.

If now I assume $v$ is a solution of the differential equation that is not constantly $v_0$, it suffices to observe that case when $v(t)>v_0$ for some $t$. By the uniqueness of solution of solution of initial value problem, we have $v$ must not cross $v_0(t)$. Therefore, $v(t)>v_0$ for all $t$. Also, since $v'=f(v)$ is negative when $v>v_0$. We have $v(t)$ is decreasing. By monotone convergence theorem, $v(t)$ has limit. Intuitively, $v(t)$ should converges to $v_0$ as $t\to \infty$. But I got stuck in writing down the proof.

Comment: The proof is indirect. If $v$ converges to $v_*$, then $v'$ converges to $0$. Thus, using that $f$ is continuous, $f(v_*)=0$. But the only root of $f$ is $v_0$.